# Discord.py Making a server only command

Tags: python, discord.py

So I'm trying to make a check-in command which only works in a specific server due to how the channels are organized. Is there a way to check where the command is being run and block it if it isn't from this specific guild/server?

My command im trying to lock to a specific guild.

```py
@commands.command()
#something here to check guild?
async def checkin(self, ctx):
    category = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.categories, id=catID)
    checkinem = discord.Embed(title='Realms Channels')
    
    for channel in category.channels: # or text_channels or voice_channels
        realm, emoji = channel.name.split('-')
        checkinem.add_field(name=realm, value=emoji, inline=False)
        
    checkinmsg = await ctx.send(embed=checkinem)
    for channel in category.channels: 
      realm, emoji = channel.name.split('-')
      await checkinmsg.add_reaction(emoji=emoji)
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks once again!

Comment: The `ctx` parameter contains the `discord.guild.Guild` object of the guild the command was executed from, is that what you are looking for?

Answer (score 1):

```py
@commands.command()
@commands.guild_only()
```

or you can do what Abdulaziz suggested if you want a specific guild

Answer (score 0):

You can do a check at the begining of the command.

```py
@commands.command()
async def checkin(self, ctx):
    if ctx.guild.id is not 1234564789: #This is the wanted guild id
        return
    #code here
```